String formatting with object parameters in intellij
I am creating a standard function that uses jpa's createQuery function, as it will be a generic class, I can format the sql elsewhere, but when using the same pattern and definition of parameters only the entity manager query presents the object correctly.
I tried adding annotations and analyzing what causes it to format in the inner class, but I didn't find what it was.
I know it can be replicated, since spring uses the @Query annotation, and the entity function too.
What I want is that when my function generates the sql in string, the link object is also visualized, which makes it easier to visualize the parameters in sql
createQuery of entity manager
enter image description here
My function has the same parameters and the same signature, but it does not display the formatted object or help with creating the sql
enter image description here
enter image description here
I don't think it's a case of intellij configuration, but I think it's missing some tag or something related to similar execution
I would like to have a function that easily shows the sql as it will be easier to create sqls, as I will create a generic function to facilitate querying with jpa

As per the [ask], please do not post images of code, data, error message, etc. Instead, copy or type the text into your question, formatted as code. Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

The IntelliLang plugin supports JPA and JDBC drivers by default, so these methods will automatically be highlighted with SQL.
If you want to define a method that accepts a SQL statement as a parameter, using @Language would be the easiest way:
String myMethod(@org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language("sql") String statement) {
    return statement;
}

If you just want to define a variable without an additional annotation, it should be:
// language=SQL
String s = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1";

See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html#edit_injected_fragment

That's exactly what I wanted, adding the parameter made it identify the objects. I am very grateful, thank you very much

The function in Kotlin looks like this, and the object in which I can access the properties by string is highlighted.
override fun queryEntity(@org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language("sql") sql: String): Optional {
val q = em.createQuery(sql, clazzEntity)
return Optional.of(q.singleResult)
}

@ElPsyCongrouMenatWorking In addition, this definition can avoid explicitly passing in the generic class, inline fun <reified T> createQuery(qlString: String) { em.createQuery(qlString, T::class.java), see also https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters
